# Failed to debug the Windows Azure Cloud Service Project. The output directory does not exist. / Azure SDK 2.3 / VS 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, azure-sdk-.net, azure-emulator

I have Azure SDK 2.3 installed on my Windows 7 machine. The target .Net framework is set to 4.0.  I'm able to upgrade my solution to Azure SDK 2.3 and build with no problems. However, when I try to run the solution, I get the following error:

***Failed to debug the Windows Azure Cloud Service project.  The output directory does not exist.***

If I revert the solution back to Azure SDK 2.2, the problem goes away.  So there's some configuration that's added by the Azure SDK 2.3 upgrade that is causing this issue.  This ONLY happens when I'm running the Azure Emulator.  One thing I've noticed is that the build process somehow removes the "Debug" folder from the csx directory.  When I manually add it back in, the build process removes it again and then I get the same error above.  I'm at a loss as to what might be causing this since my "Active solution configuration" is all set to DEBUG for "Configuration" and ANY CPU for "Platform".  I've tried all the troubleshooting steps from earlier threads on this issue (with Azure SDK 1.8) with no luck.  I would appreciate any helpful suggestions on this.  Thanks.

NOTE:  Interestingly enough, if I deny all rights to the DEBUG folder in CSX, the emulator launches but then it fails because it doesn't have access to the DEBUG folder.  So I'm puzzled by why the VS build process wants to remove that Debug folder.

ANOTHER NOTE:  Apparently, it's the normal process for VS Build to wipe out the Debug folder.  The run process with debug is supposed to recreate that Debug folder with everything in it.  That doesn't happen.  I confirmed this by reverting it back to Azure SDK 2.2 and noted that the run w/ debug actually recreates that Debug folder.  This recreation process fails to happen when I upgrade to 2.3.

Comment: Still an issue in 2018. Gotta love Visual Studio's undocumented magic config files or what not that get messed up to cause this problem... will try a full repo checkout later on to see if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by simply uninstalling Azure SDK 2.3 and then re-installing it.  That's it!

Comment: You have got to be kidding me?!

Comment: This is sooooo true.In general it simply doesn't work once you restructure your solution projects.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the issue was I changed the `Debug` Solution Configuration to something other than `Debug`. Renaming it back to `Debug` fixed the issue.

Comment: This is also the cause for me. Which really sucks cause I can't run my custom build configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Got it solved by doing the following:

1. Change to "Release" configuration.
2. Build and run.
3. Change back to "Debug" configuration.
4. Build and run. No error now.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same error that the csx folder was empty. Doing the following fixed my issue:

[Right click your *.ccproj > Debug > Start New Instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLRaw.png)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, what did work was deleting the file

`{YourProject}.ccproj.user`

Close and reopen VS, build and run